# Oracle SQL - Return records where date1 is within 24 months of date2

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm quite new to SQL but I've been asked to write something I don't fully understand.  I'm looking to select records where a date is within 24 months of another date.  Something like :-

```
select * 
  from table 
  where (date1 within 24 months of date2)
```

So for example, if date1 was 01/01/2010, where date2 has the following values the corresponding records in the table would be returned:-

```
05/09/2009
01/02/2008
06/03/2011
```

but where date2 is, for example, 25/12/2013, the corresponding data in the table would not be returned.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE date1 >= add_months( date2, -24 )
   AND date1 <= add_months( date2, 24 )
```

Your sample data isn't clear as to whether you want to include dates that are exactly 24 months earlier or later or not-- you can obviously adjust the `<=` and `>=` to be `<` and `>` if you want to omit dates that are exactly 24 hours apart.

An Oracle `DATE` column always has both a day an a time component.  The query I posted will compare dates including whatever time is present.  If you want to set all the time components to midnight, you can use the `trunc` function (i.e. `trunc(date1)` and `trunc(date2)`).  If you `trunc(date1)` in the predicate, however, you won't be able to use an index on `date1` in your query.  You could create a function-based index on `trunc(date1)` instead, however.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the add_months method:

```
select * 
from table 
where abs(months_between(date1, date2)) <= 24
```